# How to input min and max for sliderInput dates

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was wondering if someone can give me a hand figuring out the min and max for a sliderInput on a parameterized Rmarkdown that takes dates as input. If I run the rmarkdown without parameters it works well because it uses the `value:` from the yaml but when running with parameters I get the following error: `Error in min(value) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument`. Example below:

````
---
title: "Salmon Program"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date())`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    keep_md: yes
params:
  glimpse: no
  Runs:
    label: Salmon Runs
    value:
    - W
    - S
    - F
    - L
    input: select
    choices:
    - W
    - S
    - F
    - L
    multiple: yes
  Dates:
    input: slider
    min: as.Date("2012-01-01") #I get an error here
    max: as.Date("2012-01-04")
    value: 
    - !r as.Date("2012-01-01")
    - !r as.Date("2012-01-04")
    step: 1
---

# Chinook Runs in the Columbia River

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', fig.height = 4, fig.align='center',warning = FALSE, message = FALSE,comment="",echo = FALSE) 
library('here')
library('tidyverse')
```

## Import datasets

```{r,echo=TRUE}
## Subset to variables of interest
salmon2$SampleDate <- as.Date(salmon2$SampleDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
salmon2 <- salmon2 %>% 
  filter(race %in% params$Runs,
         SampleDate >= params$Dates[[1]] & SampleDate <= params$Dates[[2]])
   
Warning: Error in min: invalid 'type' (list) of argument
  47: validate_slider_value
  46: <Anonymous>
  44: param.ui
  43: FUN
  42: lapply
  41: server
   4: <Anonymous>
   2: rmarkdown::knit_params_ask
   1: knit_with_parameters
Error in min(value) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `as.Date` is an R expression you have to prefix with `!r`. And if you want to pass multiple values from an R expression you have to wrap them in a `list` or `vector`:

````
---
title: "Salmon Program"
date: "`r format(Sys.Date())`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '4'
    keep_md: yes
params:
  glimpse: no
  Runs:
    label: Salmon Runs
    value:
    - W
    - S
    - F
    - L
    input: select
    choices:
    - W
    - S
    - F
    - L
    multiple: yes
  Dates:
    input: slider
    min: !r as.Date("2012-01-01")
    max: !r as.Date("2012-01-15")
    value: !r c(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-04")) # or: as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-04"))
    step: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: That's great @stefan. I spent a whole afternoon trying to figure out. Thank you much!!!